# Duplicate ITelemetryInitializer in TelemetryConfiguration

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I see that sometimes the TelemetryConfiguration object gets set with a TelemetryInitializer more than once (This could be due to various *legitimate* reasons. Example - A TelemetryInitializer is set once from the AppInsights.config but is also set in the Startup.cs of my service.)

[image]

My question: Does that effect perf for sending telemetry to app insights? Is same initializer called multiple times or is AppInsights smart enough to figure this out? Should I check whether to add a initializer before adding?

Answer (score 0):

All configured initializers will be called in the sequence they are listed for all telemetry events, there is no smart logic behind it to avoid calling an initializer if it's mentioned two times in that list. The code does not know if it was an intent or it was a mistake, so the code proceeds as is.

You can make your initializers re-entrant, so that it bails out next time if the field you'd like to add is already there, but it's better to only invoke it once for the performance reasons.